# Can one implement a image background in his forms?

Tags: netbeans6.5

Is there a way that one could implement an image background in hos application(from)

Answer (score 0):

Per http://forums.netbeans.org/topic4381.html&highlight= , "make your panel a JLayeredPane and put the Component that you're attaching the image to the "lowest" one" should work,